# Whats the benefit of using scalaz Tag instead of a case class

Tags: scala, scalaz

```
case class KiloGram[A] (value:A)  

val mass= KiloGram(20.0)
```

With the scalaz Tag we can do something like this:

```
import scalaz._

sealed trait KiloGram


def KiloGram[A](a: A): A @@ KiloGram = Tag[A,KiloGram](a)

val mass = KiloGram(20.0)
```

Now, if we actually want to use the value of a Tagged object, we have to unwrap it

```
val twoTimesMass=2*Tag.unwrap(mass)
```

So I don't really see the benefit I gain over using a case class

```
case class KiloGram[A] (value:A)  

val mass= KiloGram(20.0)

val twoTimesMass=2*mass.value
```

I actually find the second approach much less verbose

Comment: A better question would be "what's the benefit of using a scalaz tag instead of a value class (`extends AnyVal`)"

Comment: Didn't mean to reduce it to AnyVal's, so I edited the post

Comment: A case class has overhead, a value (AnyVal) class doesn't, in a similar manner to the tag. I personally stopped using Tagged types because of problems in serializing them using  json4s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can easily write generic code which works for any `Tagged`, such as `map[A, B, Tag](x: A @@ Tag)(f: A => B): B @@ Tag`.
2. According to [the documentation](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.2/scalaz_2.11-7.2.2-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.example.TagUsage$)

   > one has to be very careful when using value classes, because there are a lot of instances in which using a value class will incur a runtime boxing/unboxing of your value, which incurs a runtime cost. The scalaz tagged types will never cause boxing of a value.

   Though the last sentence seems to be wrong since Scalaz 7.1: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/676, https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/837.

Note that you can avoid calling `value` for case classes in most cases with

```
object KiloGram {
  implicit def unwrap[A](x: KiloGram[A]) = x.value
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a little concrete example of point 1, I don't really get it...what is the x doing in your map function?

Comment: Well, you have a function multiplying mass by 2 for `KiloGram`. The problem is when also want to do the same with `Gram`, `Ton`, `Meter`, etc. With case classes you need to duplicate it; with `Tagged` you can write just one generic function.

Comment: ok, I see, something like this:
def multiply[A<:Double,Tag](tagged: A @@ Tag, times: Double)={
  val unwrap = Tag.unwrap(tagged)
  times * unwrap
}

val kgs = multiply(KiloGram(20.0),2)
val m = multiply(Meter(20.0),2)

Comment: Yes (well, in this case just use `tagged: Double @@ Tag` and remove `A` parameter).